# A hr element next to another full sized element (bootstrap 3.3.7)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get the `<hr>` element next to my Icons, I set the style of Display to `.inline-grid` to let the hr element stay right next to my Icons.
The Problem is that I need to give it a width to because inline-grid takes it full size width.

How can the hr element be full size and still be between the Icons?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <span style="cursor: pointer">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
          <hr style="width: 100px;margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;display: inline-grid;margin-bottom: 0px;"/>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

Edit: the `<hr>` element should still be horizontal. (Icon *horizontal line* Icon) <= this should take the complete row width.

Edit2: wrong bootstrap Version in snipped. Changed to 3.3.7.

Comment: Use row and col for width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead display inline-grid use display flex.

```css
hr {
  flex:1;
}

.wrapper {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">V</span>
      <hr/>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">V</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh damn, I just saw that I didnt use the right bootstrap version in my snipped. I am using Version 3.3.7 and this methode dont work with this verion :/ I will edit my question. If you still now an answere for bootstrap 3.3.7 post it too and let the other code here as "code for bootstrap 4.0". When I got enough rep for voting, you will get +1.

Comment: okey, I just copied the classes from 4.3 to my page and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Set these properties in style `vertical-align: middle;    margin: 0;`

Comment: The `<hr>` element should still be horizontal, it should just take the whole space like a unmodified `<hr>` element.

Comment: @LastChar23 i updated my code use these style on hr

Comment: That dont seem to work. Now the Icons are close above and under the line. ps, you could add the snipped from my question to your answere and modify it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
<div class="row">
<span style="cursor: pointer">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">V</span>
  <hr class="m-0 pl-3 pr-3">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">V</span>
</span>
```